# Turntable Fixture dilemma

Tags: product-photography, rotation

As it stands, I've been looking into a contract for doing product photography for a small company that sells custom race car parts and services, and I am running into one challenge that I haven't been able to over come.

The customer wants several of their more high-dollar products shot in a 24-angle 360deg.
I've got access to a +750lbs rated turntable and stand, and the ability to program it for the different degrees of motion.

The issue comes from the large brake discs.  They are quite large and heavy, and they need to be rotated radially, not axially, so they need to be standing up.

An example of what I'm trying to achieve can be seen here:
[O'Reillys](https://www.oreillyauto.com/detail/b/brakebest-select-drum-rotor-hub-2926/brake-systems-16456/brake-drums-rotors-16509/brake-rotor-11306/d133f11235f8/brakebest-select-brake-rotor/780196rgs/2546492?pos=46)

In that example, I can't figure a way to support it that doesn't require repositioning the fixture multiple times throughout one rotation, or requires extensive cloning out/ compositing multiple shots etc.. for each frame. And I will be doing over 200 of these, so 200 x 24 would be to much for the timeline if they need more than the normal Lightroom adjustments, and the occasional spot healing brush.

I'm trying to figure out how this example could have been shot.  A pin through the table doesn't seem like it would work because the rotor weighs 60lbs and has a strong bias to one side, so it bent the pin that I was using.

What would be the best way to recreate the 360° shot in the example?

Comment: If the pin you're using is bending, get a more robust pin.

Comment: I am confused about why you need a +750lbs turntable? Is the product going to be like the one in the link?
I mean I am doing turntables all the time for smaller products like [this one](https://www.prophotostudio.net/360-product-photography/) How large and how heavy are the discs? The larger item I did was a mannequin. [This one can hold 180lbs](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01M7XLBQG/ref=sspa_dk_detail_0?pd_rd_i=B01MG7W0OP&pd_rd_w=Kje6s&pf_rd_p=f0355a48-7e73-489a-9590-564e12837b93&pd_rd_wg=LDaFQ&pf_rd_r=BDEPHWDNAQWBEW8FJXM1&pd_rd_r=e6f219e5-849b-44e1-841a-4f51af11fa91&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaW

Comment: If photographing the brake discs requires additional work, price the additional work into the contract (with a markup of course). A higher price with markup is much better than a lower price without.

Comment: It's doesn't NEED to support that. the unit I happened to already have HAPPENS to support that.

Comment: I'm already charging more for the turntable shots, but I have hard time believing that the professional responsible for that sample had the composite shots and clone out a stand for all 24 shots in the 100's of parts in their inventory.